# org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element with using FluentWait

Tags: selenium, fluentwait

I change from WebDriverWait to FluentWait because it was deprecated and now I'm getting an error

```
private val waitForElement = FluentWait(DriverFactory.driver).withTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(1)).pollingEvery(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
```

```
@Step("Choose button")
    fun Wizard() {
        waitForElement.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(firstPage.wizardLocator))
        firstPage.wizardLocator?.click()
            ?: throw IllegalStateException("could not locate the wizard button")
    }
```

Getting this error:

```
Message: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element
```

Comment: Was WebDriverWait really deprecated?

Comment: @MateMrše Kinda... it was removed from the core libraries and moved into its own library. The error message that you get when you try to use WebDriverWait clearly states this.

Comment: @ JeffC Yeah, I have noticed it in the meantime. :=)

Answer (score 0):

As per [ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable-org.openqa.selenium.By-)

> An expectation for checking an element is visible and enabled such that you can click it.

You are supposed to use the above function when you're sure that the element exists at the page but you want to wait until it can be interacted with. You're getting the exception because the element is not present at the page at all.

So the options are in:

- use [.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html#ignoring-java.lang.Class-) to suppress the exception if/when the element is not present in [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model)
- or even better first use [presenceOfNestedElementLocatedBy()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#presenceOfNestedElementLocatedBy-org.openqa.selenium.By-org.openqa.selenium.By-) to ensure that the element is there and once it is at the page - you can perform another wait for its "clickability"

More information: [How to use Selenium to test web applications using AJAX technology](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/)